# Undefined variable when writing JS in blade

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="address" id='address_{{$seller->id}}' value="">
```

JS:

```
function store() {
    document.getElementById(subtotal).value = {{ $seller->location()->address }};
}
```

When I tried to re-write the value of the input in stead of "{{ $seller->location()->address }};", error occurs, said: Undefined variable: seller.
How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it isn't in the same scope?

Comment: I defined $seller in HTML.blade.php, and write JS code in another .blade.php file, then I use @include('HTML.blade.php') to combine these two files, should have a same scope, right?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get the same scope when including code from other files